# Fully Server Side Rendering in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular6, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

The angular universal loads the first page and then waits for the whole application to be loaded in background. Once the application is loaded, it swaps the view and starts rendering from client side(traditional angular way). 
So in my existing angular application I've 4 routes to 4 different components. I want this routes to be rendered from the server as separate page. Is it possible?

Basically, I want all my http calls to be made from the server so that its hidden from the client. If this is not possible, are there some templating engine which can be integrated with angular?

Please share some resources for this approach.

Comment: why do you use angular? It does not seem you need it anyhow

Comment: Kind of defeat the purpose of SPA no?

Comment: Its an existing angular application @smnbbrv

Comment: agreed @penleychan

Comment: You do not need to use angular in that case.. try looking at `JSF` or `PrimeFaces`